# Can't boot windows anymore?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows, xubuntu, uninstall

Installed xubuntu, restart computer, and it instantly boots up into xubuntu, when usually I have the choice of booting into windows as well as an old installation of ubuntu I downloaded a long time ago. What do I do?!?

I apologize, I'm a big newbie and was very naive for installing this without putting more thought and effort into this.

Comment: please add `sudo fdisk -l`

Comment: please also add the output of `sudo os-prober`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have chosen to erase and use whole disk for Ubuntu, so other operating systems have been removed. Normally, when you install Xubuntu alongside other operating systems, those systems are visible in the GRUB menu. If not, then it looks like your Xubuntu is the only operating system installed right now.

Comment: But, it still shows my old hard-drive on my desktop?

Comment: Can you access the files on that disk? Do you recognize Windows specific folders like Users, Program Files etc.?